# How do I remove comments from the end of a line

Tags: csvhelper

I am using csvhelper and my csv file contains comments at the end of a line with normal csv data. The library complains that it found bad data. Is there anyway I can remove these comments when the library tries to parse the record?

Here is an example of the csv:

```
1,2,3,"Steve says \"goodbye\""
5,6,7,"Dave says \"hi\"" # just an example comment
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to remove them at the end of the line.  You can ignore them when the comment is the only thing on the line.  You are likely also getting the bad data found on the first line.  Properly escaped CSV would look like `1,2,3,"Steve says ""goodbye"""`

Comment: I changed the configuration so it uses `\ ` as the escape character so that is escaped correctly for my circumstances. I decided to just change the `BadDataFound` error to throw a custom exception if the last field contains a `#` then I can show an error message so I can change it by hand